# How To Find Phrases Inside a Large Text Using C?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, text

**Remark**: I know there are many similar questions on SO, but none specific to the C language, hence why I am asking this.

**Here's the problem I am facing**: I will be provided a large text (e.g., 150,000 words) and after that a series of phrases (each phrase has from 1 up to 10 words). For each of those phrases I need to find the word that immediately follows the phrase in the text and return it.

**My only idea to solve it so far**: create a struct that holds:

- the current word
- the 3 words that preceded that word
- the word that follows

Then I would parse the text creating one struct for each word, and store all those structs on a hash table. As each phrase comes along I would search on the hash table for the last word of that phrase, check if the previous 3 words match, and then return the next word. I believe going to back to 3 words would be enough to uniquely identify phrases, but I could increase that number.

Do you think this would work? Do you know a better way?

Comment: Depends on how fast you need it to be. Until the requirements are intense, I would just use `strstr(whole_text, phrase)+strlen(phrase)`.

Comment: I need it to be pretty fast. In this case I think my solution would be faster than strstr, right?

Comment: Are you talking about hundreds or thousands of queries per second? Or do you just need a single query to finish in a fraction of a second? I think `strstr` should meet the latter criterion but not the former. Surely your approach should be faster, but programmer time is also worth something... :-)

Comment: First, do a naïve implementation (using `strstr()`.) *If and only if* that's too slow should you worry about a more complex approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much easier approach: run through the text, storing all *n*-grams (subsequences of *n* words) for 1 <= *n* <= 10 in a hash table or trie. Retrieval is then trivial, just look up the *n*-gram in the hash table or trie.

In the hash table version, you'd just store the *n*-grams as concatenations of word strings with normalized space in between.

The problem with this approach is that with a hash table, you'll need up to 45 * *N* entries, where *N* is the number of words in the text. Lookup should be very fast, though, and 150.000 words is a small enough dataset to make this work.

Comment: The process to build and store all n-grams doesn't look that simple to me, but I'll give it some thought, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A suffix tree is what you need. You can try Wikipedia for a first introduction to the subject.

You can consider two versions of suffix trees:

- character-based
- token-based

Comment: Not sure if this would work if you need to store 150,000 words on the tree. Would it?

Comment: 150k words is just a small data set.